# Constructing a nested tree from an org heading hierarchy

Tags: org-mode

I have a custom tangling function traverses an org file.

It matches the nearest heading or block.

If it matches a heading it collects a list that looks like `(level header tags)`. If it matches a source block it records `(switches body)`.

For example if this was the data...

```
* lion
** zebra :hi:
*** horse
#+begin_src elisp
(+ 1 1)
#+end_src
** cheetah
* dog
```

This would be what my matches would look like.

```
(1 "lion" "")
(2 "zebra" ":hi:")
(3 "horse" "")
("" "(+ 1 1)\n")
(2 "cheetah" "")
(1 "dog" "")
```

As I'm looping and collecting these matches. I'd like to build a representation of my org file as a nested list.

```
'((heading 1 "lion" ""
   (heading 2 "zebra" ":hi:"
    (heading 3 "horse" ""
     (block "" "(+ 1 1)\n")))
   (heading 2 "cheetah" ""))
  (heading 1 "dog" ""))
```

This is what the building of the result would look like at each iteration:

```
;; First iteration.
'((heading 1 "lion" ""))

;; Second iteration.
'((heading 1 "lion" ""
   (heading 2 "zebra" "hi")))

;; Third iteration
'((heading 1 "lion" ""
   (heading 2 "zebra" "hi"
    (heading 3 "horse" ""))))

;; and so on...
```

How could I achieve something like this?

Comment: This should help: https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html#global

Comment: An example on how to apply this: `(org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'headline
  (lambda (headline)
    (let ((level (org-element-property :level headline))
          level))))`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I was aware of the api. The reason I haven't used it is because it's very heavyweight. Using it requires me to load org, then open my large org file, and then parse it, and then map through the elements I've parsed. I already have the information I need from using `re-search-forward` and `string-match` in my tangling function. What I'm unsure of is building the tree itself.

Comment: Very glad I found this. I'm keen on understanding this because I want to create a graph representation, e.g, graphviz style of the contents of org-mode files, headings and links-wise. But first I've got to grok the org-element lore, then figure out a graph database data structure strategy.

Comment: @147pm I found out a very easy way to do this using recursion. I need to find it in my git stashes, I'll post it when I do.